# Need help to add url path as an endpoint point for minio

Tags: minio

I have deployed standalone Minio in a server. I also have my backend running in it. So the enpoints would be something like this:

```
Minio URL: https://example.com/minio

Backend URL: https://example.com/api
```

When I tried to setup Minio configuration in my node project, I get error. Can you help me in setting this up?

Here is my code:

```
  let client = new Minio.Client({
        endPoint: 'example.com/minio',
        useSSL: true,
        accessKey: 'xxxxx',
        secretKey: 'xxxxx'
      })
```

Comment: how did you setup minio server with this path `example.com/minio`?

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri I configured the port number for MINIO_OPTS and added a proxy pass in the nginx for the path

Comment: I do not think you can add a `/path` on Nginx conf file in such a way. I have configured Minio server with Nginx but using sub-domain not `/path`. e.g. `s3.example.comf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways we can do this:

1. Add a subdomain like minio.example.com in the endpoint
2. We can configure a particular port in MINIO_OPTS and we can redirect to the port when we have "/minio"